# Why my android chrome address bar logo is not website's logo?

Tags: android, google-chrome

As the picture shows.  This is the chrome browser on my android phone.  The icons on the left side of the address bar of all websites are in the style shown in the screenshot.  My chrome is up to date.

I want to know why my chrome address bar always shows this icon.  I hope the address bar can display the website's logo normally.  I want to get chrome back to normal.

Comment: Don't know why the picture disappeared.  Screenshot here    https://github.com/xmexg/temp/blob/main/Screenshot_2023-09-22-08-05-54-816_com.android.chrome-edit.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found answer at "https://blog.chromium.org/2023/05/an-update-on-lock-icon.html".

"Based on these research results from ourselves and others, and the broader shift towards HTTPS, we will be replacing the lock icon in Chrome with a variant of the tune icon. "

"The new icon is scheduled to launch in Chrome 117, which releases in early September 2023, as part of a general design refresh for desktop platforms. Chrome will continue to alert users when their connection is not secure. You can see the new tune icon now in Chrome Canary if you enable Chrome Refresh 2023 at chrome://flags#chrome-refresh-2023, but keep in mind this flag enables work that is still actively in-progress and under development, and does not represent a final product."

Answer (score 0):

A method to change the icon on the left side of the android chrome address bar to the lock icon:

open "`chrome://flags/#omnibox-2023-refresh-connection-security-indicators`"
then turn the switch to Disable.